# jquery on() isn't working with click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, events, click

This is my jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div#overlay div#getFBid div#overlayClose").on("click", function(){
        console.log("test")
    });
});
```

And this is my html, which is called with ajax:

```
<div id="overlay">
    <div id="getFBid">
        <div id="overlayClose">&nbsp;</div>
        <h1>Wat is mijn Facebook page ID?</h1>
        <div id="fbPageURLholder">
            <input type="text" id="fbPageURL">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, I'm obviously missing something that should be really simple I think.
Any thoughts?

PS. I should add to this that I saw on jquery.com that the live function is deprecated and I should use delegate or on.

Comment: working fine here http://jsfiddle.net/CG8up/

Comment: Works here: http://jsfiddle.net/faceleg/bghdS/ The HTML isn't in an iFrame is it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This:

```
$("div#overlay div#getFBid div#overlayClose")
```

can be reduced to

```
$('#overlayClose')
```

since you'll only ever have one element of that ID in your document.

As for the problem; if you've loaded the content with AJAX, it won't be available in DOMReady, when you're binding your listener.

To bind to elements that have not yet been added, you need to use a live delegate:

```
$(document).on('click', '#overlayClose', function() {
    console.log('test');
});
```

Where `$(document)` should be something as close to the element as possible, that *is* available at DOMReady, and that is not destroyed.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that, thank you for solving my problem so quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Did you import jQuery?

That works for me, clicking Close will log a test message in the console:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"       type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="overlay">
        <div id="getFBid">
            <div id="overlayClose">Close</div>
                <h1>Wat is mijn Facebook page ID?</h1>
                <div id="fbPageURLholder">
                    <input type="text" id="fbPageURL">
                </div>
            </div>
     </div>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#overlayClose").on("click", function(){
            console.log("test")
        });
    });
</script>
```

Hope that helps.